Vacation duration on a UK skilled worker visa
I have a UK skilled worked visa till 2026. I entered the UK last December and want to visit my home country for vacation in October. My company gives me 20 days of annual paid leave and I saved all 20 days for this vacation. I have a couple of questions:

Do I have to be out of the UK for exactly 20 days counting from the day I fly or can I add 4 weekends (8 extra days) to the 20 days? This means I am out of the UK for ~30 days if I travel on a Saturday and my leave duration starts from Monday.
Do I have to inform the home office about my vacation dates?
What kind of documents do I have to show to the immigration guys at the airport upon my return to the UK so that they let me in?


@Abhi Bhagat What makes you think that you might have to inform the Home Office about a vacation? Or that the documents you need to show to the IO on your return would be any different to those you showed when you last entered the UK on your current visa?

As a Skilled Worker you can leave the UK for as long as you like without restriction. However if at some point you wish to apply for Indefinite Leave to Remain, you must have spent less than 180 days outside the UK in any 12 month period. Those are the only restrictions imposed by the government. There is no need to inform the government of your travel. Presenting your travel document (passport) and your visa will get you back into the country.
Normally in the UK when a company offers "20 days leave" it means 20 days you would have worked, so not counting weekends and public holidays. You can absolutely take four complete weeks, including the weekends before and after.
It might be a good idea not to fly back on the very last day before you start work, to guard against flight delays and jet lag.

Based on the question posters comments on another answer, it might be worth clarifying what things going wrong would look normally like (i.e. that the company would need to have grounds to fire them, then withdraw sponsorship).

I'm not sure what could go wrong?  The OP plans on using their vacation to travel home. As long as they don't exceed the vacation I can't see what could happen.

The OP seems to be under the misapprehension that it’s the Home Office interested in/tracking their holiday days, rather than the sponsor (to be fair given how e.g. Student route visas work with irregular holidays there is plenty of information on “UK visas” that can give that impression).

(+1) I suspect the OP may be concerned about any mechanism by which governments enforce restrictions on the employers' behalf or makes entry or exit contingent on having received permission from one's employer, cf. no-objection certificates in India, exit visas under the kafala system, etc. It may be useful to add that no such system presently exists in the UK.


That's 20 full calendar days (not business working days as you suggested). However the exact day upon which you leave, and the day upon which you return do not count against those 20 days. So if you can leave early enough on that first day, even if you were only in the UK for just a few hours before you flew out, that whole day counts as being in the UK. That said, see the edit below.

You do not have to inform anybody in the government about your vacation dates. It's all recorded on the system whenever you cross borders.

Just your visa (presumably) in your passport. That's it.


Edit: It seems there is some confusion about the relationship between the OP's employer and the government of the United Kingdom. My answer assumed that the OP was wanting maximize their stay outside of the UK while minimizing the number of days counted actually towards the 180 day total they are allowed. From the comments, it is clear that OP mistakenly believes there is some sort of mechanism between their employer where vacation days are tracked. This is not the case! As far as residency in the UK is concerned, the Home Office will only be interested in your total stay outside of the United Kingdom - not the reasons why (with some very specific exceptions for compassionate grounds or obviously violating the terms/spirit of the visa).

my 20 days annual paid leave is only for business working days & doesn't include weekends.

@AbhiBhagat, The Home Office doesn't care about your employer's holiday arrangements or their interpretation thereof. They only care about the dates you enter and are residing in the country, and the dates you aren't.

sure but what i am still scratching my head over is a simple question - what are the reasons immigration may deny me an entry if my employer has already approved my 4 weeks leave. i will not be spending a day over 4 weeks.

@outflak As far as I know, on a skilled worker visa you can be outside the UK for up to 180 days. Where are you getting this idea that you can only be outside for 20 days according to government rules?

@DJClayworth, Quite obviously, neither I, nor the OP, are talking about the overall limit you can be outside of the UK. The OP, I think clearly, wants to be outside of the UK 28 days, but only have 20 of those days count towards time out of the UK. edit: Just saw their latest comments. Looks like the OP is confused about the relationship between his employer and immigration rules. Guess I'll update my answer.

@AbhiBhagat, I think there may be some confusion here. Your personal time off from your work is irrelevant to the Home Office. It doesn't matter what reason you are out of the UK. As long as you have a valid visa to return (you still meet all of the original conditions of its issuance), you will be allowed back in under the conditions of that visa. The reasons you are outside of the country don't matter at all.

”what are the reasons immigration may deny me an entry if my employer has already approved my 4 weeks leave? An overseas employee may be terminated, and hence their Skilled Worker sponsorship cancelled, for a number of reasons, including:

Redundancy
Poor performance
Prolonged absence
Non-attendance at work
Employer’s sponsor licence revoked by the Home Office

